# Change font color in Shiny tableOutput

Tags: r, shiny

What is the easiest way to change the font color of a single row dataframe with tableOutput. Specifically, how to change the "7" under "Right" to green.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(  
         tableOutput("view")
        )
      ),

      mainPanel(
      ))),

  server = function(input, output, session){

    correct <- reactiveValues(num = 7)
    wrong <- reactiveValues(num = 4)   
    skipped <- reactiveValues(num = 9)

    togo = 80

    output$view <- renderTable(tibble(
      Right = correct$num,
      Wrong = wrong$num,
      Skipped = skipped$num,
      ToGo = togo
    ), spacing = "xs")
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `DT` in this case that comes with `renderDataTable` for better formatting.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fluidRow(  
          column(8,dataTableOutput("view"))
        )
      ),

      mainPanel(
      ))),

  server = function(input, output, session){

    correct <- reactiveValues(num = 7)
    wrong <- reactiveValues(num = 4)   
    skipped <- reactiveValues(num = 9)

    togo = 80

    output$view <- renderDataTable(datatable(tibble(
      Right = correct$num,
      Wrong = wrong$num,
      Skipped = skipped$num,
      ToGo = togo
    )) %>% formatStyle("Right",color=styleEqual(7, "red")) ) 
  }
)
```

#### Show Table Only:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fluidRow(  
          column(8,dataTableOutput("view"))
        )
      ),

      mainPanel(
      ))),

  server = function(input, output, session){

    correct <- reactiveValues(num = 7)
    wrong <- reactiveValues(num = 4)   
    skipped <- reactiveValues(num = 9)

    togo = 80

    output$view <- renderDataTable(datatable(tibble(
      Right = correct$num,
      Wrong = wrong$num,
      Skipped = skipped$num,
      ToGo = togo
    ), options = list(dom = 't')) %>% formatStyle("Right",color=styleEqual(7, "red")) ) 
  }
)
```

Comment: That option brings up a lot of functionality that I wish to hide. Is it possible to hide: Show entries <10>, Search box, Small up/down arrows next to column names, Row name, "Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries" and Previous/Next?

Comment: Great. Thank-you. Still have those overkill triangles though.